# SQL Solving with Subqueries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm a beginner trying to learn and practice SQL with tables based on this schema:

- `EMPLOYEE` - `ID, Name`
- `ASSIGNMENT` - `ID`, `Country`, `Start`, `End`

The primary keys are `Employee.ID` and all four columns shown for `ASSIGNMENT`; and `ASSIGNMENT.ID` is a reference to `EMPLOYEE.ID`. The domain of start and end is in years.

**Problem:** I'm trying to write a query that will display all the employees (by name) where they were assigned to an assignment in the USA directly after they had completed an assignment in Canada.

This is my current attempt, which fails to compute. I believe I am heading in the correct direction but there are syntactical mistakes.

```
SELECT 
    E.Name
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN 
    ASSIGNMENT A ON E.ID = A.ID
WHERE 
    (SELECT End FROM ASSIGNMENT 
     WHERE Country = 'Canada') = (SELECT Start FROM ASSIGNMENT 
                                  WHERE COUNTRY = 'USA')
GROUP BY 
    E.Name;
```

Any critique to benefit my understanding of my misconceptions are welcome. My errors are coming from the combination of the subqueries in the `WHERE` clause

> At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

Perhaps someone can show me another way to compute this?

This query is being tested in MS Access since I found it easy to build a database and relationships quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subqueries use another join and add constraints to the join conditions:

```
SELECT 
    E.Name
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN 
    ASSIGNMENT A ON (     E.ID      = A.ID 
                      AND A.Country = 'Canada' )
INNER JOIN
    ASSIGNMENT B ON (     E.ID      = B.ID 
                      AND B.Country = 'USA'
                      AND B.Start   = A.End    )
GROUP BY 
    E.Name;
```

***Update***

The OP reported an error from MS Access complaining about the composite join condition for the above version. However, you may safely move inner join conditions to the where clause. The interim resultsets will grow, though, since the product of the tables is produced first with less constraints and filtered thereafter (A good query optimizer might avoid the unnecessary generation of records, but I do not know about the capabilities of MS Access in this regard).

```
SELECT 
    E.Name
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN 
    ASSIGNMENT A ON ( E.ID = A.ID )
INNER JOIN
    ASSIGNMENT B ON ( E.ID = B.ID )
WHERE
        A.Country = 'Canada'
    AND B.Country = 'USA'
    AND B.Start   = A.End
GROUP BY 
    E.Name;
```

Comment: Looks good! Seems like a more logical approach.Unfortunately, I am getting errors with this revision using Access . Once the parentheses are adjusted for multiple joins, an error prompts on the line "AND B.Start = A.End", saying "JOIN expression not supported".

Comment: I'm a bit rusty wrt MSAccess quirks ... too busy with a _real_ rdbms ;-). See the update to the answer for an alternative solution. You may alsotry a 'mixed mode', ie. only move the offending condition to the where clause.

Comment: I agree. MSAccess is already showing it's limitations in my brief experience. I moved your original code over with the same Database into MS Studio running SQL Server and it ran flawlessly. Thanks!